# Blazor authentication using AzureAD - for Accounts in any organizational directory

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor

I am trying to set up a Blazor Wasm application to be able to authenticate the user from any organizational directory. But when the user attempts login, they get an error if the email is not in the users list for the Azure Entra ID directory.

Here is how it is called in program.cs:

```
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

Here is the appsettings.json.  I have tried both organizations and common for the TenantId value.

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "Domain": "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "organizations",
    "ClientId": "myclientid012345678",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
}
```

Supported account types is:
Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)

[image: Error message]

Comment: This is net core 7

Comment: Can you please share the error..

Comment: Error message added in problem description

Comment: Once try by removing the Scopes in `appsettings.json` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **AADSTS50020: User account 'User@xxx.onmicrosoft.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/xxx/' does not exist in tenant 'Contoso' and cannot access the application 'xxx'(ClientAppRuk) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first.**

Initially I got the **same error**:

[image]

The error usually occurs if the Microsoft Entra ID application is not configured as **"*Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)*"** to allow access to other tenant users.

- In the code, you need to pass **TenantId** as
  **`organizations`**.
- And also make sure to pass the **Authority** as **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations`**.

I created **`ServerAppRuk`** and Exposed an API like below:

[image]

Created  **`ClientAppRuk`** and granted API permissions:

[image]

For both the applications make sure to select ***"Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)"*** option:

[image]

**To resolve the error,** make sure to pass **Authority** as **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations`** like below:

*Client App `appsettings.json` file:*

```cs
  "AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations",
    "ClientId": "ClientAppID",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  }
}
```

[image]

And make sure the Server App **`appsettings.json`** file looks like below:

```cs
{
     "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "organizations",
    "ClientId": "ServerAppID",
    "CallbackPath": "RedirectURL",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user"
  },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

[image]

Make sure to **add client application in the Server app** configuration like below:

*Pass the ClientID of the Client application*

[image]

After the above settings, **I am able to successfully login to the application with another tenant user**:

[image]

[image]

**References:**

[Client application configuration (MSAL) - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-client-application-configuration#authority)

[Secure a hosted ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly app with Microsoft Entra ID | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-microsoft-entra-id?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: You got me REALLY close to succeeding, and then I get hit by this little gem of an error: 
"Log in There was an error trying to log you in: '9002326 - [2024-03-18 15:54:49Z]: AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type. "

I remember specifying single-page-application somewhere in the EntraId area, but I am running Blazor Wasm. Any idea of how to rectify this impedance-mismatch?

Comment: Ignore my last "comment".  I found a boo-boo in my setup.  Great solution, many thanks for your help on this!!!

Comment: @GeorgeHelmke did you solve your issue?